# Java design for command / status message managing

Tags: java, design-patterns, command, message

I am developping a java TCP client which consists of a set of commands as XML messages. The client shall be able to send commands asynchronously with a specific user interface, receive acknowledgement messages and the status from the server if any. I have also specific GUIs designated to configure the data of each command. The different command data models must be accessible by the various views and controllers in the client package.

The problem is simple but I would like to make it the right way because the interface specifications between clients and the server is really subject to evolutions (new messages, messages used in one project but not in another one, duplicated messages but one parameter is different, etc...) So, what I was looking for is maybe a design pattern or a composed one which could fit my needs or if any of you had to make a client like this and could give me some advices on what to do or not to do.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view I would suggest to use publish/subscribe model. As a implementation you can use [EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) from google-guava.

```
public class MyEvent {
   String description;

   public MyEvent(String description){
       this.description = description;
   }
}
```

Next component is subscriber which is able to receive events:

```
public class MySubscriber {
    @Subscribe
    public void handleMyEvent(MyEvent event) {
       //do some logic
    }
   .....
```

Last part is publishing an event into eventbus:

```
EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
MySubscriber mySubscriber = new MySubscriber();
eventBus.register(mySubscriber);

eventBus.post(new MyEvent("Some description"));
```

You can now register subscribers in a different parts of application and react on incoming event eg. XMLMessageEvent

Comment: Seems to be a good way to handle the message events :) So now I have to find how to represent and store my message's data model